# Using Cypher, is it possible to get relationships names in a path that its length is not predefined?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to get all the paths between two nodes that have a length of 1 to 3. I would like to retrieve all of nodes and relationships between them.

I am using the query:

```
MATCH p=(p1:DOG)-[:A|:B|:C*1..3]->(p3:PERSON)
RETURN p
```

I do not get the relationships type. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a concise way to return a collection of the relationship types in the path:

```
MATCH (:DOG)-[rels:A|:B|:C*1..3]->(:PERSON)
RETURN [r IN rels | TYPE(r)];
```

When you match a variable length path, the relationship with the `*` (`rels`) is a *collection* of relationships. So, you just need to extract the `TYPE` of each relationship.

Answer (score 2):

The relationships are in the path object that is returned.  You just have to pull them out into a collection using `relationships` and then return the type of each one. Something like this...

```
MATCH p=(p1:DOG)-[:A|B|C*1..3]->(p3:PERSON) 
WITH relationships(p) as rels
UNWIND rels as r
RETURN type(r)
```

This might illustrate something you are looking for a little better

```
MATCH p=(p1:DOG)-[:A|B|C*1..3]->(p3:PERSON) 
RETURN reduce( path_str = "", r in relationships(p) | path_str + startNode(r).name + ' --> ' + type(r) + ' --> ') +
(nodes(p)[length(p)]).name
```